# module "twitter" has no attribute "Twitter"

Tags: python, module

I have the following file, twitter.py, which defines a class called Twitter:

```
class Twitter:

     data = {}

     def __init__(self):
         pass

     def tweet(self):
         print("I'm tweeting")
```

And I have another file, `main.py`, in the same directory as `twitter.py` which imports twitter and attempts to instantiate the class:

```
import twitter

twitterObj = twitter.Twitter()
```

Unfortunately, Python throws the error message: `AttributeError: module 'twitter' has no attribute 'Twitter'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce this error on my machine. I'm assuming you have a module with the name "twitter" installed to your python path that is overriding the project file. Try renaming twitter.py.

Comment: I'll add that to avoid this issues in the future you may want to look into tools like virtualenv (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to prevent module collision.